# How to split delimiter array values into another Array

Tags: linq

```
string[] sArray = { APPLE|apple, SOURCE|source, BIOS|bios, APPLE|device };
```

Above is the string array, and I need to split these array and get before values of pipe symbol `**|**` using LINQ.

Now am using like this to get into array:

```
List<string> lVirtualDir = new List<string>();
foreach (string _sArray in sArray)
{
  lVirtualDir.Add(_sArray.Remove(cus.IndexOf('|'), _sArray.Length - _sArray.IndexOf('|')));
}
```

This above code will get result as

```
APPLE
SOURCE
BIOS
APPLE
```

I need to sort this code part in LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
lVirtualDir = sArray.Select(x => x.Split('|')[0].Trim())
    .OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```